# Python, find the length of the (n)n string by regex

Tags: python, regex

i have a code looking like this:

```
import HTSeq
reference = open('genome.fa','r')
sequences = dict( (s.name, s) for s in HTSeq.FastaReader(reference))
out = open('homopolymers_in_ref','w')

def find_all(a_str,sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)
homa = 'AAAAAAAAAA'
homc = 'CCCCCCCCCC'
homg = 'GGGGGGGGGG'
homt = 'TTTTTTTTTT'
for key,line in sequences.items():
    seq = str(line)
    a= list(find_all(seq,homa))
    c = list(find_all(seq,homc))
    g = list(find_all(seq,homg))
    t = list(find_all(seq,homt))
    for i in a:
##        print i,key,'A'
        out.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(key)+'\t'+'A'+'\n')
    for i in c:
        out.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(key)+'\t'+'C'+'\n')
##        print i,key,'C'
    for i in g:
        out.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(key)+'\t'+'G'+'\n')
    for i in t:
        out.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(key)+'\t'+'T'+'\n')
out.close()
```

I used HTSeq to open the reference. What it does - it looks for simple homopolymers of length 10 and outputs start position, chromosome and type (A,C,T,G,).

THE sequence always looks like:
ACCGCTACGATCGATCGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGATCGAC
sometimes it contains N

so our homopolymer that we are looking for is:
AAAAAAAAAA (or other composed of only C,G,T)

Basically the help from you is about the find_all function only:
Now what I would like to change is finding the length of each homopolymer. Since, right now if a homopolymer has a length 15, my script can't tell it.
I was thinking of doing it by some sort of regex, namely: find at least 10 bp like now and compute length by adding +1 to it until the next base isn't like those in homopolymer.

Any suggestions how to use a regex to do it in python?

Comment: Can you define homopolymer?

Comment: it's one of hom* variables. In simple words - string of the same letters - ex. AAAAAAAAAA. Inmy case the string has to be of length at least 10. but I want to find the exact length of the homopolymer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this with a regex you can try something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> seq = 'ACCGCTACGATCGATCGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGATCGAC'
>>>
>>> [(m.group(), m.start())
...     for m in re.finditer(r'([ACGT])\1{9,}', seq)
...         if len(m.group()) >= 10]
[('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 17)]
```

This produces a list of `(sequence, start_index)` tuples.

Comment: cool. But as always I oversimplified what it should do. First thing, only A,C,T,G, no N characters. Other thing, where can I put the information about: where this sequence starts? The key information from my dictionary is also pretty important for me